# CKeditor with 2 textareas is no sending all fields changes

Tags: php, ckeditor

I have a form in php that has 2 textareas, this form uses ckeditor in those textareas

When send it, i receive the changes of the first textarea and the data of the second textarea without changes

The html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="../css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/dropdown_menu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/funciones.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/funciones.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="container">
    <div id="head"></div>
    <div id="menucontainer">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a id="Actualizaciones" href="../noticias/noticias.php" title="ACTUALIZACIONES" >ACTUALIZACIONES</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="Correo" href="../correos/correos.php" title="CORREOS" >BOLETÍN DE NOTICIAS</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="Salir" href="../usuarios/logout.php" title="SALIR" >SALIR</a>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
    <div id="submenucontainer">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--    
    var menu = new DropDownMenu($('menu'));
    -->
    </script>
    <div id="menuizq">

        <ul class="sec">
            <li ><a href="../usuarios/usuarios.php">Cambiar Contraseña</a>
            </li>
            <li ><a href="../usuarios/logout.php">Salir</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="administracion">
    <div id="titulo">Actualizaciones</div>
        <form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div >
            <div class="fm-fila " >
                <div class="fm-campo" >
                    Titulo:<br /><input name="txt_titulo" type="text" id="txt_titulo" autocomplete="off" maxlength="60" value="Trazabilidad por Productos" tabindex="1"  onKeyPress="return tabular(event,this)" class="input_pre" />
                </div>
                <div class="fm-campo5" >
                    Fecha:<br /><input name="txt_fecha" type="text" id="txt_fecha" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" value="20/08/2013" tabindex="2"  onKeyPress="return tabular(event,this)" class="input_pre" />
                </div>
                <div class="fm-icon" >
                    <img src="../img/icons/date.png" width="16" height="16" align="top" onclick="displayCalendar($('txt_fecha'),'dd/mm/yyyy',this);" style="cursor:pointer" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fm-fila " >
                <div class="fm-campo2" >
                    Entradilla:<br />
                    <textarea name="txt_entradilla" id="txt_entradilla" tabindex="3"  class="ckeditor"  rows="8"/>prueba 1</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fm-fila " >
                <div class="fm-campo2" >
                    Detalle:<br />
                    <textarea name="txt_detalle" id="txt_detalle" tabindex="4"  class="ckeditor" rows="8"/>prueba 2</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fm-fila " >

                <div class="fm-campo2" style="text-align:center;">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fm-botonera" >
                <input type="button" name="guardar" id="guardar" class="bto-guardar" tabindex="5" value="Guardar" onclick="javascript:validar()"  style="margin:6px 0px;"/>
                <input type="button" name="cancelar" id="cancelar" class="bto-cancelar" tabindex="6" value="Cancelar" onclick="location.href='noticias.php'"  style="margin:6px 0px;"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="txt_id" id="txt_id" value="32" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The php code is:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['txt_entradilla'];
echo $_POST['txt_detalle'];
?>
```

If I take out the first textarea the second sends the changes and if I place first textarea "B" and then the textarea "A", the textarea "A" don’t have the changes.

I'm using CKeditor 4.2.

i upload my files to mediafire, here is the link: http://www.mediafire.com/?x73h2sjq8ku63ih

Comment: is this web page online, so i can look at the post headers?

Comment: no, i test it using a local wamp server 2.4 and firefox 25.0

Comment: looks ok to me, only way i could only debug it if i had aceess to it- good luck.

Comment: my files are uploaded in http://www.mediafire.com/?x73h2sjq8ku63ih